# (C++) Using curses to print new line read in from file

Tags: c++, file-io, output, ncurses

The following is in a text file

> To the north, is the entrance to Room 2.\nThere are six suspects in this room:\n\tAdam\n\tSofia\n\tLucas\n\tDaniel\n\tChris\n\tJack\n\tTiana.

This line is being read in and being stored.
I am trying to use printw() to output this with the lines and tabs, however it just prints out as is with the '\n' and the '\t'. What are some possible solutions to this?

Comment: Before storing the string from the text file, scan for `\x` sequences and replace them by the escaped character they represent.

Comment: I just tried this. Now it prints to the first '\n' and stops printing

Comment: I got it working! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the printf() function. By checking the documentation they are the same functions, couldn't find the differences.